# Google Chrome runs too slow vs. Mozilla Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, performance, connection

I have both Firefox and Chrome installed in a Windows 7 device.

Firefox works very well and it doesn't hangs and it's also super fast.

BTW in playing videos firefox in all of my devices is slow and choppy in compare to chrome.

In this machine Chrome hangs on even its home page and if I type some links, multiple times the hang pop-up comes up, also the cpu usage is 100%.

Any idea?

---

Edit:

System Spec:

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate

RAM: 2 gb

CPU: Intel Celeron D 3.06GHz 3.07GHz

Comment: What's your hardware?

Comment: @gronostaj added.

Comment: @JohnD.J. Have you got the latest version of Chrome? And what extensions have you got, if any? 
Also, next time Chrome is acting up, go to the Chrome menu, 'More tools > Task manager' and there you will see what exactly is using up the cpu, whether its a process or extension etc.

Comment: @NetServOps Latest version,  There aren't any extensions installed,  Ok I'll do that and I report it.

Comment: This is a 15 year old CPU which, even when it was launched in 2006, wasn’t the fastest available, with an absolute minimum amount of memory (2GB). This machine is simply underspecced for running the latest version of Chrome. You’re using an O.S. that has been out of support for more than a year.

Comment: @StarCat then why firefox works

Comment: Firefox might be less dependent on modern CPU features, CPU speed or memory size. I don't know, I'm just pointing out the obvious. You can't expect too much from modern software running on ancient hardware and O.S. The fact that Firefox runs satisfactorily is nice, but I would not expect all modern software to run well. Have you looked at CPU and memory use of Chrome?

Comment: @StarCat On another system with the same spec but with an Intel Celeron 2.80 GHz 2.81GHz CPU the Chrome works great, seems strange

Comment: Again, there might be all sorts of reasons for that. Look at CPU and memory utilization and maybe that will give you a clue as to what is causing the bottleneck.